# android - how to show an image depends on 2 spinners value?

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, spinner

i have 2 spinners with 10 values each,
now what i want is when the user selects the 2 values returns a specific picture on another activity called "YourPath"

here is the code for the first activity

```
private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button btnSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationlist);


    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    LocationList.this).create(); // Read Update
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Message");
            alertDialog.setMessage("You are in "
                    + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())
                    + "\nAnd You are going to "
                    + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()));

            alertDialog.setButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            launchIntent();

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setButton2("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
        }

        private void launchIntent() {
            Intent it = new Intent(LocationList.this, YourPath.class);
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
        }

    });

}
```

}

now do i need a database to do that !!!

do you have any ideas about how can i do that !!!!

thanks

Comment: you would need to pass the spinner positions into the intent and then make a conditional statement to load an image based on those retrieved values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need a database at all.  In fact, the only reason you would is if you want to dynamically change the images that are possible for users to end up on "your path".

If you can provide all of the images while creating the app, simply put them all in the /Drawable folder, and then you will access the one you want in the YourPath Activity.

I would grab these values and put them in a variable to use them like this:

```
String value1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String value2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then, I would stick a couple of string values into the intent you are sending to the YourPath activity.  You will do that in the launchIntent method like this:

```
private void launchIntent() {
        Intent it = new Intent(LocationList.this, YourPath.class);
        it.putExtra("value1", value1);
        it.putExtra("value2", value2);
        startActivity(it);
    }
```

Then, in your YourPath class, grab these values like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

String value1 = extras.getString("value1");
String value2 = extras.getString("value2");
```

You will then do some if-else (or preferably switch) statement to figure out which image to show

```
if(value1.equals("somevalue") && value2.equals("othervalue")){
    int imageResource = R.drawable.mypic;

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
```

**Then add your my_path layout file to res/layout folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You should now be able to access the image view in your myPath activity, just dont forget to set the content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_path);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but in the last section of the code what should i put instead of "myPic" and "my ImageView" and how should my xml looks like am sorry that i ask many questions but am a beginner

Comment: I changed my code slightly above.  So start by creating a new folder under /res called /drawable.  Put all of your images in here.  Then, access them in code by calling their id.  For example say you put mypic.png into drawable, you can access it by calling R.drawable.mypic.  I will add the XML layout you will need for this activity above.  For now It will simply be an image view that takes up the entire screen.  And don't worry, we all start out this way!!

Comment: thank you very much you saved my life sir oooh what can i do to thank you more !! i really appreciate it if you just gave me you email or anything so i can contact you in the future